# modelFor parent route stopped working as before

Tags: ember.js

Given the following routes:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'locations', path: '/:location_id', ->
    @route 'events', path: '/events/:date'

App.LocationsEventsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    location_id = @modelFor('locations').get('id')
    console.log location_id
```

Accessing "/#/gothenburg-se/events/2013-09-03", `location_id` returns `null`. This worked before v1.0. What changed and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to changes in Ember Data for 1.0.beta.1.  You might want to check out the transition document.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

I think something like this would work for your route:

```
App.LocationsEventsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model : function(params){
    // find returns a promise
    var locProm = this.store.find('location',params.location_id);
    // once the promise has resolved you can log the id
    locProm.then(function(loc){
      console.log( loc.get('id') );
    }); 
    // return the promise immediately and let Ember resolve it
    return locProm;
  }
});
```